# AngularJS $LocalStorage cleared but setInterval working yet

Tags: angularjs

I have an issue with a snippet, it works like if i update anything in on tab, the other tab should change (calling GET function)

And my snippet works very well in this case, here you go for my snippet:

```
$scope.updateContact = function (contact) {
    $http.put('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/contact/' + $scope.clickedContact.id + '/?=format=json', $scope.clickedContact)
    .then(function(response){
      $scope.successEdit = 'You have updated the contact successfully';
      $scope.getAllContact(); // this function will make sure to reload the page after edit
      $localStorage.editedData = response.data;
      $scope.editedID = $localStorage.editedData.id;
      if (response.data.id == $localStorage.editedData.id) {
        $localStorage.isChanged = true;
      }
      $timeout(function(){
        $scope.successEdit = '';
      },4000);
    }, function(response){
      var errorData = response.data;
      $scope.errorEdit = Object.values(errorData)[0][0];
      $timeout(function(){
        $scope.errorEdit = '';
      }, 5000);
    });
  };


  setInterval(function() {
    if ($localStorage.isChanged == true) {
      $scope.getAllContact();
      localStorage.clear();
    }
  }, 5000);
```

I hope you notice a setinterval in the end of the snippet:

```
setInterval(function() {
    if ($localStorage.isChanged == true) {
      $scope.getAllContact();
      localStorage.clear();
    }
  }, 5000);
```

Problem with this,

I want when localstorage changed, so that it call this function  `$scope.getAllContact();` and after that, it should clear `localstorage` It works but the problem is, it works continually even the localstorage cleared.

I want like this below:

1. When localstorage data changed, it should call this fuction `$scope.getAllContact();` and then clear the local storage. and even if later another change happens, the function `$scope.getAllContact();` execute again and then clear again **but problem is now it is executing and clearing even it is not waiting for another change happens, it continually executing after only one change occurs. how can i make it to wait to execute again after another change occurs?.**

Comment: I think you need to make `$localStorage.isChanged = false` after clearing localstorage.

Comment: No it not works

Comment: You can also use angularjs service $interval instead of setInterval()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take in a variable

```
var clearInterval = setInterval(function() {
    if ($localStorage.isChanged == true) {
      $scope.getAllContact();
      localStorage.clear();
    }
  }, 5000);
```

and clear  like that

```
clearInterval(clearInterval);
```

Comment: I dont get this, clearInterval(clearInterval); can you help me write this?

Comment: @mamuncode you can call `clearInterval(clearInterval);` after `localStorage.clear();` line. It will stop execution of `setInterval`

Comment: i did it but execution is not stopped

Comment: please check https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp . hope it will helpful for you

Comment: Yes, It works but when there is another change occurs, why it is not start again?